# Как можно узнать модель видеокарты ноутбука чтобы поставить проприетарный драйвер

Tags: ubuntu, драйвер, видеокарта

Есть ноутбук HP 250 G5 Notebook PC и система Ubuntu 20.04. Сейчас сижу на встроенной в процессор видеокарте intel corporation HD Graphics 5500. В ноутбуке есть Видеокарта Amd Radion R5 Serias. Помогите определить модель видеокарты точнее, чтоб поставить драйвер, а то программно ее не определяет, а на сайте AMD там еще 3 подсерии. Может как-то в биосе можно посмотреть?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
$ lspci -vnn |grep -iE  "vga|display"
```

или так:

```
$ grep -i chipset /var/log/Xorg.0.log
```

или с использованием утилиты lshw:

```
$ sudo apt-get install lshw
$ lshw -short | grep -i display
$ sudo lshw -class display
```

Comment: попробовал на своем ноуте (у меня правда NVIDIA), обе команды показывают только встроенную ителовскую.

Comment: добавил в ответ третий способ